# get dataTable filter by widgetVar which is a composite attribute to clear filter

Tags: primefaces, datatable

My p:dataTables are all generated in a composite attribute. Because there is more than one table on a site sometimes I need to link the widgetVar to a variable. I used a composite attribute for that.

Everything works fine but I can't find a way to access the datatables by their widgetVar to clear the filters, my code:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="CC_tableName" type="java.lang.String" />
</composite:interface>

<p:commandButton value="clear"
                 onclick="PF(#{cc.attrs.CC_tableName}).clearFilters()" />

<composite:implementation> 
    <p:dataTable 
        widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.CC_tableName}" 
        >                               
    </p:dataTable>
</composite:implementation>
```

My problem is this part: PF(#{cc.attrs.CC_tableName})

The widgetVar of the table is set correctly, I can access it when I enter the tableName directly in the onclick attribute of the button, but then only 1 table on each site works correctly...so how can I get the dataTable by using the composite attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, it was pretty simple. You need to add the '' altough it's a variable, so this one works:

PF('#{cc.attrs.CC_tableName}')